# Telerik's AppBuilder not grouping files

Tags: telerik, nativescript, telerik-appbuilder

I am using the AppBuilder to create a NativeScript app.  I am at the point that I need to start looking into environment settings to get the app ready for QA and production.

I followed the article: http://docs.telerik.com/platform/appbuilder/nativescript/build-configurations/application-settings in order to set the config.js file I have that contains some configuration information.  I created config.debug.js and config.release.js but Visual Studio only added the debug version under the config.js file group.

So, when I build in Debug mode, the app picks up config.debug.js and everything is fine.  When I try to build in release mode, the app crashes because it cannot find config.js.  Attached is a screenshot that shows how Visual Studio sets the files.

[image]

It seems to me that since the release version is not included in the file group nativescript does not recognize it during the build.

I am using Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise.  App Builder 2017.1.202.9

Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you [submit a support ticket](https://www.telerik.com/account/support-tickets/my-support-tickets) so that our support engineers can look at your project more closely? This is an issue that we can't replicate without more info from you. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Preslav from Telerik, I deleted the .debug.abproject from the root of my application and also removed the reference to it in MyProject.iceproj.

Once this was done, I was able to create the .debug.js and .release.js files without any further issues.